# jquery scroll, change navigation active class as the page is scrolling, relative to sections

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/gUWdJ/

I'm after a jquery scroll technique please that I would like to adapt to my project.

Please see my project example as a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/gUWdJ/

Currently you can see that my nav links automatically animates the scrolling relative to the `<section>`'s.

My question is, using the `$(window).scroll` method, how can I add a `.active` class to my `nav a` when the sections reach the top of the window?

So for example if the user scrolls down the page (instead of the navigation links), I want the active class to be added relative navigation link. Indicating where you are on the page.

*The active class will have to be removed then added every time I'm guessing as the user scrolls down the page.*

Also you will have to account for the 28px height of the fixed navigation bar, offset top window.

Can anyone please show me a technique that I can try and use or adapt, or perhaps show me using my jsfiddle :)

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/gUWdJ/

[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you wish a more generic function:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/3/)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windscroll >= 100) {
        $('nav').addClass('fixed');
        $('.wrapper section').each(function(i) {
            if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll - 100) {
                $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
                $('nav a').eq(i).addClass('active');
            }
        });

    } else {

        $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
        $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('nav a:first').addClass('active');
    }

}).scroll();​
```

Comment: This is awesome!!! Alot more trimmed than I imagined. Thank your for taking the time and sharing this method with me!

Comment: Your welcome, but i suggest you to change $(this).position().top <= windscroll - 100  to $(this).position().top <= windscroll - 20  SEE: http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/3/  Otherwise its buggy when you click on nav A.

Comment: Ahhh I did just spot that, it was getting a little confusing when mixing the button actions with scrolling. The second fiddle works great now thanks!!! +1

Comment: Hello @roasted - I'm really sorry to bother you, but could you take a quick look at my most recent question regarding this topic. You'll probably be able to fix it easily (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048437/data-scroll-and-data-anchor-active-class-is-off).

Comment: Hello @A.Wolff - I'm really sorry to bother you, but could you take a quick look at my most recent question regarding this topic. You'll probably be able to fix it easily (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65414249/make-the-change-of-active-class-in-the-menu-more-reliable-when-scrolling)

Comment: Hello, what if the menu is on the line and has overflow-x, how would it be done to move the scroll horizontally according to the option, I say it in case it has 9 menus and the person is seeing it from a mobile

Answer (score 7):

You can do this way: http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/1/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() < $('section[data-anchor="top"]').offset().top) {
       $('nav a').removeClass('active');
    }

    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('section[data-anchor="top"]').offset().top) {
      $('nav a').removeClass('active');
      $('nav a:eq(0)').addClass('active');
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('section[data-anchor="news"]').offset().top) {
      $('nav a').removeClass('active');
      $('nav a:eq(1)').addClass('active');
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('section[data-anchor="products"]').offset().top) {
      $('nav a').removeClass('active');
      $('nav a:eq(2)').addClass('active');
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('section[data-anchor="contact"]').offset().top) {
      $('nav a').removeClass('active');
      $('nav a:eq(3)').addClass('active');
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for showing me this method. This is great too if my content is fixed. I used the answer above cause I'm trying to build it into a dynamic menu. Thanks

Comment: Great! We are here to give solutions. Thanks for the considerations.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and modified my script off of A. Wolf because I needed to make sure that my menu items lit up with a negative top difference instead of at 0. This works a lot better than creating a separate function and avoids having to create a click event for each menu item. I would also modify this script to account for the last item in the menu, it should be automatically highlighted if the second to last item is. I suppose mine is very similar but different as I handled my each loop outside of the my main highlight function. The other great thing about my modification is that accounts for having images inside of a link inside of a menu item and accounts for the height of a element and when the bottom of that element hits the top of the page, which is when the highlight should end before a new one does.

```
function highlight(item)
{
var itemTop = jQuery(item).position().top;

var windowTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop(); 
var topDifference = (windowTop - itemTop); 

var itemHeight = jQuery(item).height();
var bottomDifference = topDifference - itemHeight; 

var menuId = jQuery('#nav-icons li a').attr('href');
if (menuId = item)
{
    if(topDifference > -1 && bottomDifference < 0)
    {
        jQuery("#nav-icons li a[href='" + item + "']").parent().addClass('active');
        jQuery("#nav-icons li a[href!='" + item + "']").parent().removeClass('active');
    }
    else {
        jQuery("#nav-icons li a[href='" + item + "']").parent().removeClass('active');
    }
}
}
jQuery('#nav-icons li a').each(function(){
var eachAttr = jQuery(this).attr('href');
highlight(eachAttr);
});
```