# Active Class while page scrolling

Tags: jquery

Developing a single page (body scroll top animation )
Please check demo first and see add/remove active classes on 'menu li a'
http://jsfiddle.net/sUMaa/1/

Everything is fine but single problem
Need same active class function while we page scrolling with the mouse

```
jQuery('ul li a').click(function(){
        var idName = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        var idNameFixTop =  jQuery(idName).offset().top; 
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:idNameFixTop}, 1000);

        jQuery('ul li a').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Do you mean that when something like contact comes into view on scroll, the contact link should become active?

Comment: Yes you are right @ryadavilli

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery scroll, change navigation active class as the page is scrolling, relative to sections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161132/jquery-scroll-change-navigation-active-class-as-the-page-is-scrolling-relative)

Answer (score 1):

Although I understand your problem, implementing this on your own may raise some tricky questions:

- How much of the element should be visible before the navigation element is set active
- What to highlight if more than one element is currently visible

To make your life easier, use something like the [jQuery Waypoints plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/). Take a look at the [Docs](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#docs), you can control pretty much everything.

Example for your code:

```
$('div').waypoint(function() {
  $('ul li a').removeClass('active');
  var currentIndex = $('div').index($(this));
  $('ul li:eq(' + currentIndex + ') a').addClass('active');
},
{
  offset: 'bottom-in-view'
});
```

Comment: Here's a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sUMaa/2/ -- working perfectly, I added `offset: 'bottom-in-view'`

Answer (score 1):

Either way, you can use [twitter bootstrap Scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy), works fine :)