# Data-scroll and data-anchor — active class is off

Tags: jquery, html

I'm developing two sites, [Fredrix Design](http://www.fredrixdesign.com) and [Bosted System](http://bosted.fredrixdesign.com), where I use the exact same "one page"-system files and code that I got from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14161592/1329669) on Stack Overflow.

On Fredrix Design it works perfectly — the navigation menu slides the user to whatever `<section data-anchor="example">` he/she clicks on via `<a data-scroll="example">`. However it doesn't work the same way on the Bosted System website. The sliding mechanism works smoothly as it should, but the `active` class is off by 20 pixels or so. It doesn't change exactly when I arrive at a different `<section>` — it changes when I've entered it.

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/3/)

supplied/made by [@roasted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/roasted) in the other question mentioned above.

Comment: Hi, Frederick! Doesn't look like same html structure on both sites. The Bosted site has sections wrapped in a 'scroll' div, maybe some CSS properties affect expected behaviour.

Comment: I would say you need to check for some of these value wich ones make it buggy:  `scrollPoint = $('section[data-anchor="' + scrollAnchor + '"]').offset().top - 84;`  or ` if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll - 20) `   E.g  why 84 ?

Comment: Thanks for the respond, @roasted. CSS properties was my first thought, but I haven't been able to crack it. The `scroll` class was just a quickly placed div to work as a `wrapper` like used in the demo (http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/3/). I noticed that by removing the `wrapper` in the demo, I'd get the same result in the Fiddle as I have on the Bosted System. 84 just made the `header` stop at the right spot (right before the `<section>`). Isn't that the reason for it?

Comment: Would implementing some sort of `wrapper` do it, you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Bosted site, setting window scroll handler like this seems to fix your problem. You should investigate in this way to find what's going on but i think its due to some padding/margin property somewhere:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windscroll >= 100) {
        $('section').each(function(i) {
            if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll + 84) { // << here '+ 84' instead of '- 20'
                $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
                $('nav a').eq(i).addClass('active');
            }
        });

    } else {
        $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('nav a:first').addClass('active');
    }

}).scroll();
```

Comment: This is, pretty rad. Hoping that an extra comment and vote help more people see this little gem. EDIT: Not just Bosted, peep this little snippet homies.