# Parallax Scrolling menu highlight item

Tags: jquery, menu, scroll, parallax

I am building a site and this feature ive seen used on many parallax sites. The triangles that appear when i hover over the menu items i want to be able to stay apparent on the specific menu item when it is clicked and when the particular section is scrolled to.

So when i click on "live" the triangle should appear and stay apparent or if i scroll to that section it should show up and the same for all other sections.

Here is part of the code im working with ... let me know if i need to add more 
http://jsfiddle.net/lemonhead1374/4HRxr/

Here is the HTML both html and CSS are in jsfiddle link

```
<div class="header">
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="inner">
        <a href="#home"> home</a>
        <a href="#live"> live</a>
        <a href="#learn">learn</a>
        <a href="#mission">mission</a>
        <a href="#heal">heal</a>
        <a href="#adorn">adorn</a>
        <a href="#sip">sip</a>
            </div>
        </div>
<div>



<section id="home">
<div class="lower">
<div class="homecontainer">
    <div class="binder">
       hi all            
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>

<section id="live">
 hi alllllllllll hellllloooo
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent example [already here at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161132/jquery-scroll-change-navigation-active-class-as-the-page-is-scrolling-relative) that does what you want to do. It not only provides the code you're looking for and a jsFiddle to see it all work, but it's nice and compact and doesn't require a plugin. [See it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161132/jquery-scroll-change-navigation-active-class-as-the-page-is-scrolling-relative)

If you would prefer to use a plugin, there's an interesting one that uses straight Javascript [called skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr). It responds to the scroll event and uses a highly intuitive method for coding the breakpoints. Worth a look.

I should note that on seeing your code you have ***all sorts of problems***, not only with your basic html being very clunky (lots of nested divs and unnecessary IDs all over the place, not-even-nearly-semantic markup, etc.) but under the hood your Javascript is throwing all sorts of errors, likely because you copied large chunks of code from another site. There are all sorts of flags being thrown for cross-origin issues, webfonts and images not found, etc. Your code is a mess™. If this is a learning exercise, then it doesn't matter, I guess. But if this is client work for somebody else, you are definitely going to want to fix all that, and I'm guessing that you will need to do some homework to get started.

If you're a beginner, or even if you want a good review on proper coding technique, there are [ample resources all over the internet](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=learn%20html%20css) for learning proper html and css coding, and I would **highly** recommend going through the [tutorials at Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/web).

As previously stated, if the url you provided is just for your own study, then thrash away, it's a perfectly fair way to learn, though [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/web) might be more efficient.

Comment: thankyou, and i have the entire code some where else i just copied all of my selectors they are being used for functions other than my navigation but i didnt add that html because that wasnt the issue, . thankyou again ill try that

Comment: so i still haven't figured out how to do this... the link to the website is http://4-element-lifestyle.mybigcommerce.com/ and i think i just need a little bit more direction