# Jquery scroll, top offset for active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, offset

Can You help me please with a one thing I can't manage?

I have used scrolling-nav.js for the top menu on my website - Interior, Exterior etc. http://lukaszradwan.com/www_architect/services.php

Now I set the offset using this code

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 130) {
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
} else {
    $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
}
});

$(function() {
$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 130
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

But when you click for example to Exterior, active class is not working exactly at this position.

I tried to use method form another topic, but my "js" knowledge is poor. [jquery scroll, change navigation active class as the page is scrolling, relative to sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161132/jquery-scroll-change-navigation-active-class-as-the-page-is-scrolling-relative)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle please? will be much easier to help with one.

Comment: It would be easer to give you access to my site, there is a thousands of code lines and I don't know actually which is which.  This fiddle looks very similarhttp://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/1389/  I need scroll function like in fiddle above adjusted to my js code. Sorry for this chaos:)

Comment: is $($anchor.attr('href')) targeting the same anchor than the callToAction in your navBar ?

Comment: There is .offset().top - 130 for scrolling, and I need to set the same value for .active, but I don't know how:/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, active class is applied only when the top offset of section is 0. You can change it to other value like 130 using jquery. Add this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    /* Get id of sections corresponding to top nav menu */
    var scroll_sections = []
    $('a.page-scroll').each(function(){
      scroll_sections.push($(this).attr('href'));
    })

    for (i in scroll_sections)
    {   
      /* Instead of 0, if the top position offset of section is 130 or less,
         we add active class for that section in nav menu */
      if ($(scroll_sections[i]).position().top <= $(window).scrollTop() + 130) 
      {
        $('nav li.active').removeClass('active');
        $('nav a').eq(i).parent().addClass('active');
      }
    }
});
```