# JQuery - Navigation items change to 'current' based on section, scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation bar that when clicked takes the user to the specific section (via id). I was wondering how I could manipulate this to make it so that the nav items change to the 'current' when the corresponding view of the section is present. I have followed many original posts however, since I already have a design, it doesn't seem to work effectively. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<nav id="primary-menu" class="dark">

                    <ul id="top-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right mu-main-nav">
                        <li class="current"><a href="#" data-scrollto="#slider" data-offset="100"><div>Home</div></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-scrollto="#content" data-offset="100"><div>About</div></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-scrollto="#section-services" data-offset="100"><div>Website</div></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-scrollto="#mobile-app" data-offset="100"><div>Mobile App</div></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-scrollto="#portfolio" data-offset="100"><div>Portfolio</div></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-scrollto="#section-pricing" data-offset="100"><div>Pricing</div></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-scrollto="#testimonials" data-offset="100"><div>Testimonials</div></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-scrollto="#section-contact" data-offset="100"><div>Contact</div></a></li>
                            <!--<a href="#" data-scrollto="#content" data-offset="100" class="dark one-page-arrow"><i class="icon-angle-down infinite animated fadeInDown"></i></a>-->

                    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#primary-menu { 
    float: right; 
}

#header.full-header #primary-menu > ul {
   float: left;
   padding-right: 15px;
   margin-right: 15px;
   border-right: 1px solid #EEE;
}

#primary-menu ul {
     list-style: none;
     margin: 0;
}

#page-menu nav {
   position: relative;
   float: right;
}

#page-menu nav ul {
   margin-bottom: 0;
   height: 44px;
}
```

Comment: where is th JS, and will need and jsffidle or any to test functionality

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? It is a interesting question

Comment: nav items change to what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery scroll, change navigation active class as the page is scrolling, relative to sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161132/jquery-scroll-change-navigation-active-class-as-the-page-is-scrolling-relative)

Comment: You have not tried solving the problem yourself. This is not a "PLS CODE THIS FOR ME" service.

Comment: I really have. It's hard when you're learning, and sometimes people like me need to result to stackoverflow for a little extra help. And the nav items require to change to 'current' as updated.

Answer (score -1):

Using bootstrap scrollspy can help with this

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_scrollspy_js&stacked=h

Please refer to this link which has the example which you are looking for